# Context Disposed Error before DropDownListFor() get populated

Tags: linq, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been trying to get a DropDownList to work:

My controller code is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Register()
{
    var teams = new List<Team>();
    using (var context = new TouristContext())
    {
        teams = (from x in context.Teams select x).ToList();
    }

    var model = new RegisterViewModel()
    {
        Teams = new SelectList(teams, "Value", "Text")
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

My `DropDownListFor()` code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Teams, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTeamId, Model.Teams, "Value", "Text")
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try and access the page I get the error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I understand the error, but I have no idea how to overcome it.

Comment: Intersting, since you have .ToList() , and it should have worked fine.

Comment: This is a lazy loading problem,  but I'm puzzled Bec. U already used toList() to eagerly load items??? However,  are you sure that the team's subitems i.e.values and text are also loaded?? Or u assumed it?

Comment: @Ciwan Can you change this line of code and see if the problem exists: `Teams = new SelectList(teams.ToList(), "Value", "Text")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason it was failing was because I had nothing called `Value` and `Text`!

My properties were `Id` and `Name`, so I changed my code to:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var teams = new List<Team>();
    using (var context = new TouristContext())
    {
        teams = (from x in context.Teams select x).ToList();
    }

    var model = new RegisterViewModel()
    {
        Teams = new SelectList(teams, "Id", "Name")
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

And now all works fine.

Comment: I told u; u assumed it: p